# Formatted percentage value is not what's expected

Tags: java

```
 percentOne = (double)faceOne * 100.0 / (double)amount;
 NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
 fmt.format(percentOne);
```

If `faceOne` is 17 and `amount` is 100, then the `percentOne` becomes 1,700 %

I don't understand why.

Comment: `17 * 100 / 100 = 17`, which in percent is `1700%`?

Comment: We're going to need to see a bit more code here. Your two lines appear to have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: More specifically, `percentOne` becomes `17`.  Which makes sense, given basic arithmetic.  `17`, as a whole number, expressed as a percent of a whole (`1`), is `1700`.  This isn't a problem with Java, this is a problem with your understanding of arithmetic.

Comment: Please, set the title to something more meaningful and related to your problem next time.

Comment: Guys, please don't down vote a person who has no reputation

Comment: @Dipin: Downvotes are made on a question, not on a user.  The user's rep score is irrelevant.  It's a bad question, so the community downvotes it.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what I think was the OP's intent. I think it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
17 % = 0.17 

17 * 100 / 100 = 17  // This is the reason behind.
```

Answer (score 3):

Percentages as doubles are *less than or equal to* one -- they're a fraction between 0 and 1. So 17% is 0.17, not 17.